# Render to LandScape Mode by default on Open GL ES 2.0

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, egl

I am working on the test application available at https://github.com/libhybris/libhybris/blob/master/hybris/tests/test_glesv2.c

to test a basic GL application.

This application is working fine.
Since i am fairly new to Open GL ES 2.0 , i want to know what modification is needed in the provided source code so that the application is rendered in Landscape mode by default.
(Considering that Open GL ES 2.0 has no glRotate functions available).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by landscape mode.  If you're trying to rotate the scene, you need to be doing so by passing the appropriate matrix into your shaders.

Comment: @Jherico : Yes the orginal vertexArray is provided in the code .Can you suggest what modification is needed to that or what should be the final vertexArray so that x axis and y axis are rotated by 90 degrees ?

Answer (score 0):

You can force your application to always run in landscape mode by adding the following line to the activity definition in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity 
    ...
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    ...
</activity>
```

This way, you don't have to worry about rotating your OpenGL content.